# Eclipse Plugins - Null Pointers

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Can anyone refer me to a good eclipse plugin that will help detect possible null pointer exceptions and maybe even possible NumberFormatExceptions?

I am using a suite of Junit tests but it would be good to have a plugin also that may assist in identifying any gaps

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) it has a [eclipse plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/findbugs/index.html)